# How to change static variable inside in a class by a method

Tags: java, methods, static, static-methods, static-variables

I have three classes:

Class One

```
public class One {
   private static Two object;

   public static void set_up(Two object) {
       int y = object.get();
       System.out.println(y);
   }

   public static void prn () {
       System.out.println(object.get());
   }

}
```

Class Two

```
public class Two {
   private int x;


   public int get() {
       return x;
   }

   Two(int n){
       x = n;
   }
 }
```

Class Three

```
public class Three {
   public static void main( String[] argv ) {
       One st = new One();
       Two two = new Two(2);

       st.set_up(two);

       st.prn();
   }
}
```

I want to change the static variable `object` in class `Two` by `method set_up(Two object)`.
The problem is that static variable inside the class has the same name as the arguments in the method. How can I modify `set_up(Two object)` so I copy values from given argument to static object?

Comment: One.object = object.

Comment: @MWB this? Inside a static method? I don't think so.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Cannot use this in a static context

 at One.set_up(One.java:6)
 at Three.main(Three.java:6)

Comment: I cant really use "this" inside a static method @Zephyr

Comment: @NoName missed that; right you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can qualify it by using the class' name:

```
public static void set_up(Two object) {
    One.object = object;
}
```